# Replace an xml names with a variable

Tags: c#

I am working on SharePoint. I have two sites one main site and a sandbox. Their codes are same but xml names of columns are different. So I am trying to make a code in such a all xml names will be replaced by their variables.plzz check my code below.

```
    #if  TestSite
        public const string context = "url";
        public const string Title = "xmlname1";
        public const string User_id = "xmlname2";

    #else 
        public const string context = "url2";
        public const string Title = "xmlname1";
        public const string User_id = "xmlname2";

    #endif
```

when I debug this program it connects to url1....how will I connect it to url2?
Both urls should work for Common code.

Comment: You are aware that those compiler directives (`#if ..`) only work at compile time? So you would have to compile it specifically for each site.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to put some kind of identifier in the settings of your program. Then the user can set whether to connect to site A or B.

Sometimes you can use the URL to determine to which system you are connecting, or maybe you can even get the metadata from the service itself, removing the need to keep record of the column names to get. Then you first fetch the metadata, and then actually make the calls to the data endpoints.

Comment: Glad it helped. Feel free to accept my answer by checking the check mark before the answer given.